# Does there exist an open set $U$ in $\Bbb C$ such that the restriction of $x^2 +ixy^3$ on $U$ is holomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=x^2 +ixy^3$

Does there exist an open set $U$ in $\Bbb C$ such that the restriction of $f$ on $U$ is holomorphic?

I supposed that such function exists, then for all $z=x+iy$ in $U$, Cauchy Riemann condition holds.

If $p=x^2$ and $q=xy^3$ then 
$p_x=2x =q_y=3xy^2$. And  $p_y =0=-q_x =-y^3$

Then $y=0$
$$U \subseteq \{z \in \Bbb C | \operatorname{Im}(z)=0\}=\Bbb R \subseteq \Bbb C$$

How to continue?

Comment: Every open set in $\mathbb C$ contains numbers with at least two different imaginary parts ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm is the set R open in C?

Comment: x @Malak: Do you know a definition of "open"? Does it apply to $\mathbb R\subseteq \mathbb C$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  I don't know whether the interior of R in C is empty or not

Comment: I know that R is open in the Euclidean space

Comment: x @Malak: I'm not sure what that has to do with anything. But in any case: Do you know a definition of "interior"? Does it apply to $\mathbb R\subseteq \mathbb C$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  I know the definitions, but I worked with topology in the real space not in complex

Comment: I think if I proved that R not open in C, I will get a contradiction to what I have supposed in solving the question

Comment: x @Malak: If you know a definition (even though you seem to be strangely reluctant to reveal the definition you know), what prevents you from applying it to this situation?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  I am a bit confused, I want to make sure that i am solving correctly

Comment: x @Malak: In order to get help with your confusion, you need to reveal the definition you're trying to apply, and explain what problem you encounter when you try to apply it. Merely claiming to be confused, without more, does nothing to inform a reader what the _causes_ of your confusion is.

Comment: @HenningMakholm only one more thing that I need it to be answered plz in order to continue solving is: what is the interior of the set R in C and is it different to the interior if R in R which is the set R itself??

Comment: x @Malak: I'm not here to do your work for you. If you refuse to reveal the definition that you're having trouble applying, and refuse to reveal _what_ confuses you when you try to apply it, then this is not the site for you. Try domyhomeworkforme.com instead.

Comment: x @Malak: You're asking for "a hint" while refusing to give the information I need in order to find a hint you can use. That's not a way to get random people on the internet to want to help you. If you want anyone to help you need to stop expecting people to GUESS what your problem is. I have asked you several times now: What is the definition you have trouble applying? What is the confusion you experience when you try applying it. As long as you insist on keeping the answers to those questions a secret, I won't be able to help you.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Anw, I am not asking for solution , what I need is only a hint and I think u misunderstood me

Comment: x @Malak: Lose the national-security attitude and stop being so secretive, then.